# How to create a combined Regex for no-leading zeros, space and special characters?

Tags: regex

I have a requirement of validating string in case it has a leading zero, or space in any part of the string or special character in any part of the string

**for instance**

"0baqp d8895&&g"

in the provided string above, the string has a leading zero, a space and special character, how can i validate this kind of string.

> browsing only gives me result for validating space or special
>   character or leading zero but not all in one

**UPDATE**

**these are all valid strings**

BAqpd441587

abcdef12345

132456abcdef

**these are all invalid strings**

0abcd1324568 - because this contains a leading zero

abcdef**&&46588 - because this contains special characters

abcde 4568 - because this contains space

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Provide more examples and show your attempt.

Comment: "Special character" also needs definition, what's special in a context is normal in another.

Comment: actually i am not able to combine all the regex to acheive the main goal, if i add regex for leading zero and then add regex for space , the leading zero starts to fail, can you help me with the regex

Comment: @Aaron any special characters which can be found in the keyboard should be validated

Comment: You need to use alternation in a single regex, parts of the alternation being the patterns that match each of your criteria.

Comment: At least provide some valid and invalid examples in question.

Comment: @anubhava i have provided explanation as an update in my question, thank you for your help

Comment: Does your regex have to match valid string and reject invalid strings, or can it match invalid string and reject valid strings, relying on an above layer to revert the result? Both are possible in regex, but the second choice would lead to a cleaner regex.

Comment: @Aaron regex has to reject invalid string

Comment: @LijinDurairaj: You can use: [`^[^0]\w*$`](https://regex101.com/r/n1ku00/1) (won't allow empty input as valid match)

Comment: @anubhava careful, it will also match `_` which can or cannot be considered a special character (I still don't know what OP consider a special char, especially since space doesn't seem to be one of them)

Comment: ok in that case: `^[^0][a-zA-Z0-9]*$`

Comment: @Aaron anubhava thank you very much :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If possible, I would suggest validating by matching the invalid choices, then relying on the absence of any match to assess validity.

This is because invalid strings are simply defined : they start with a zero or contain a special character (or a space, which can be considered a special character).

The regex to match that would simply be something along the lines of `^0|[*& ]` (where you would have to list all the characters you consider special in the character class which currently only contains `*`, `&` and space).

You can try it [here](https://regex101.com/r/ce0Jkx/1), where I had to add the `g`lobal and `m`ulti-line flags to make the regex work on multiple lines inputs, which shouldn't be necessary in your case.

If the result of the regex can't be manipulated afterwards and must return the validity or the parsed string, the problem definition becomes more complex : we must match every string that start by something else than 0 and only contain character which are not special (nor space).

In that case, the regex [anubhava](https://stackoverflow.com/users/548225/) suggested (`^[^0][a-zA-Z0-9]*$`) [should work nicely](https://regex101.com/r/DTOYwl/1).

Another option would be to use a negative lookahead, but it is expected to be less efficient : `^[^0](?!.*[*& ])` (in this case too you would want to list all special characters).

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is: `((^0.*$)|(^[\w]*[\s\W]+[\w]*$))`

**Note:** This expression will MATCH invalid strings. So the strings which passes this regexp you should consider as invalid.

All your examples are tested in https://regex101.com/

Comment: A few notes if you want to simplify your regex, which otherwise seems correct : `\w` is already a character class, no need to enclose it in brackets ; `\W` contains `\s` (but not `_`!), no need to specify them both in a character class ; your parenthesis are not needed here, although they might improve readability. You could make use of them to put the `^$` anchors outside of the alternation, but anchoring the second criteria isn't needed : in this case you don't need to match every character of the input text, just the hypothetical ones that match the criteria, wherever they are in the text

Comment: Note that readability generally comes first, so if you and your colleagues read your regex more easily than the result of applying my notes, then your regex is better.

Comment: @Aaron, yes you're absolutely right. Thanks for advice.